# How do I pass the id value of a selected object to another page to select another object and build a relationship between them using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

I have a Tasks model, and Projects model. As you can imagine, Projects have many tasks and tasks belong to many projects.

I also have a table of relatoinships, where a task is related to a project.

What I don't know how to do, is: I have a page where all the tasks are shown, and another page where all the projects are shown. I want the user to be able to select a task and assign it to a project. I don't know how to pass the id of the selected task to the next page, where the projects are listed, and then with the id of the selected project create a relationship between those two id's.

could someone help me on how to approach this? I'm not sure if I should use a cookie to save the value of the task, or if there is another way to do this..

thank you very much!
Joaquin (please excuse my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're describing you'll probably want to do the association through the task's form and then check all of the projects to which the task belongs.  Your task form would look something like:

app/views/tasks/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
 <div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>
 <% Project.all.each do |project| %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag :project_ids, project.id, @task.projects.include?(project), :name => 'task[project_ids][]' -%>
      <%= label_tag :project_ids, project.name -%>
    </div>
 <% end %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in your tasks_controller's update method, you'd need something like:

```
def update
    @task = Task.find params[:id]
    projects = Project.find(params[:task][:project_ids]) rescue []
    @task.projects = projects
    if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
      …
end
```

And the link on your tasks list would be to the task's edit page which contains the above ex:

```
<% for task in Task.all %>
 <%= link_to "edit task", edit_task_path(task) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot miked!!! Exactly what I needed! since I posted this question I did manage to build the asociation through the task's form, but your code is just so much better! thank you!!

Comment: ah good, glad that worked out for you.  If you can set this answer as accepted, that'd be great too.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[First link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) when i type `rails relation` in Google Search (has_and_belongs_to_many).

When you want get all tasks which belongs to project use `@projects.tasks`. Whe you want paginate this use `kaminari` gem.

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, thanks for your answer, but my problem is not how to build an association. Every thing works fine if I manually add the a row to the relationships table, indicating the project_id and the task_id. What I don't know how to do is, -How do i allow the user to create a relationship if he/she has to select, first the task from the tasks list, and then the project from the projects list. How do I pass the value of the selected task to the next page where he has to select the project he wants to associate the task with.Many thanks!!